# Replacing a number of switch statements using functional programming in ReactJS's stores and actions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactjs

Don't know if it is just me but switch statements in ReactJS stores causes an eyesore, so I've thought maybe there's a way to replace these switch statements with a better, modular one.

So i've looked into the internet for quite some time and saw that a **functional** approach is the way.

### The Switch

```
Dispatcher.register(function (action) {
  var text;

  switch(action.actionType) {
    case Constants.CREATE:
      create(action.text)
      Store.emitChange();
      break;
    case Constants.UPDATE:
      update(action.id, {text:action.text})
      Store.emitChange();
      break;
    case TodoConstants.DESTROY:
      destroy(action.id);
      Store.emitChange();
      break;
    default:   
  }
});
```

### The Plan

```
getAction = function(action) {
   var move = {
       "CREATE": function() {create(action.text)},
       "UPDATE": function() {update(action.id, {text: action.text})},
       "DESTROY": function() {delete(action.id)}
   }
   return move[action.type](); // if key exist
}
```

### First Problem

I do not want `CREATE`, `UPDATE`, `DESTROY` as function names because it is not flexible and I have lost the use for **Constants**, so is there a way that I could still use `Constant.CREATE`, `Constant.UPDATE` and `Constant.DESTROY` as function names?

### Second Problem

So in theory I can modularize each action `CREATE`, `UPDATE`, `DESTROY` into separate files and I am using browserify.

So how can I do that?

Comment: You can define your lookup table as `var move = {}; move[Constants.CREATE] = function() { ... };`.

Comment: wew, the first problem solved, just like that :D